# Wireless devices for wireless control of light

Tags: smart-home, zigbee, lighting

**Objective:**
        Finding out about terminology/ specification to help me source 
        economically priced hardware for DIY installation. (My Google search for 
        wireless light 
        switching produces wall switches operatable by apps but physically wired to 
        the light circuit, like a mechanical switch).

**Situation:**
         I have a group of led lights, less than 100 W total. I want to operate this group through a wireless signal from a wall switch and/or touch panel. I prefer to use dumb globes connected to a device which receives the operating instruction wireless from a wall switch and /or touch panel to control the dumb globe.

**Question:**
    What hardware devices (Zigbee compatible) are required to receive the wireless signal and operate the circuit. See image below: [image] (third layout is what I am looking for)

a) for simple ‘on/off’ operation

b) for ‘on/off’ operation with ‘dimming’

c) What Zigbee compatible hardware device (instead of the conventional light switch) is required to generate the wireless signal for a), for b)?

Comment: Something like this but With dimming and zigbee? https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Sonoff-4CH-Smart-Home-WiFi-Switch-4-Gang-Wireless-Switches-Din-Rail-Mounting-Home-Automation-on/2620032_32806306337.html

Comment: @Slow learner. Thank you for that. This wall controller on Alibaba appears to be hard wired in the light circuit, if I understand the diagram correctly. The wireless condition seems to mean that the Wall controller can be wirelessly operated by app or from remote computer.

Comment: @ Slow learner. Thank you for that. On re-reading the site I realise you are right, My apologies. I was too late to retract my earlier comment. The device (receiver/ controller) could be mounted in the ceiling and wired to control 4 separate circuits independently. All I then need is a smart wall mounted device to communicate wireless to such a controller, preferably Zigbee compatible. Then the same idea for dimming.

Answer (score 2):

My first search for 'zigbee relay' came up with this [survey](https://community.smartthings.com/t/survey-showdown-vote-for-your-favorite-z-wave-zigbee-in-wall-relay-switch-modules/37981). The devices shown here seem suitable for your application (at least many of them).

[image: Dimmer/switch]

Although they are often described as suitable for fitting behind a switch, you don't have to use them like that. For a switch function, you should look for one which requires a live and neutral connection (so the device can be powered without relying on a path through the lamp).

You can chose mechanical relay devices (in effect a remote switch), or electronic switches/dimmers. The electronic switches ought to be OK with an LED lamp, but the dimmer variants are more tricky - the design of a typical LED lamp means that it will not dim as expected. To achieve proper dimming, the lamps you use will need to regulate themselves, or you need a dimming power supply for a collection of low-voltage bulbs.